# Backing up file with cp fails when using variable

Tags: bash, cp, ubuntu-22.04

Little bit stumped here. I'm trying to write a simple bash function I can call to make a backup of my current `~/.bashrc` file. The function basically does this:

```bash
backup_filename="~/.bashrc_`date +%Y%m%d`"
cp ~/.bashrc "$backup_filename"
```

when I run that however it says:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '~/.bashrc_20230913': No such file or directory
```

However if I run the same statement without the `$backup_filename` variable, it works just fine:

```bash
# This works no problem
cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc_20230913
```

I've also tried using

```
cat ~/.bashrc > $backup_filename
```

but it gives me basically the same error:

```
-bash ~/.bashrc_20230913: No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes

Comment: `~` isn't expended in a string, see above link.

Comment: ...the easy answer is to use `$HOME` instead, though `backup_filename=~/"bashrc_$(date %Y%m%d)"` -- starting the quotes only _after_ the `~` -- would work too.

Comment: Is `%Y%m%d` valid syntax?

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. If you want to add that as the answer, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @Cyrus my bad, I omitted the `+` before it. Thanks for catching that. Didn't fundamentally alter the core of the question though.

Comment: Both suggestions I made above are already covered in the answer to the preexisting instance of the question (linked up above the content of this instance). That prior instance is where I'd want to add anything that isn't already covered.

Comment: _If you want to add that as the answer_ : It is not possible to add an answer to a question which is closed.